# Failed to get frames from camera of htc one s, How to get them?

Tags: android, camera, frame

I'm new in Android programming.  I have done a project on android phone. It works well on my HTC desire a8181. Because I want my software works faster, I get a htc one s. Then the program cannot get frames from the camera.Did someone used to meet such problems before? Please help me. (I used onPreviewFrame to get the frame in my software. )

```
public class CopyOfCameraPreview extends SurfaceView implements
    SurfaceHolder.Callback, PreviewCallback {
private SurfaceHolder mHolder;
private Camera mCamera;
private boolean preview = false;
public static int w, h, l;

public CopyOfCameraPreview1(Context context) {
    super(context);
    mCamera = getCameraInstance();  
    mHolder = getHolder();
    mHolder.addCallback(this);
    mHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);
}



public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width,
        int height) {


    if (mHolder.getSurface() == null) {

        return;
    }

    try {
        mCamera.stopPreview();
        preview = false;
    } catch (Exception e) {

    }

    try {
        mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(mHolder);
        mCamera.startPreview();
        preview = false;

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Error starting camera preview: " + e.getMessage());
    }
}


public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {

    try {
        mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(holder);
        Camera.Parameters parameters = mCamera.getParameters();
        parameters.setPreviewSize(960, 544);
        parameters.setPreviewFormat(PixelFormat.YCbCr_420_SP);

        mCamera.setParameters(parameters);
        mCamera.setPreviewCallback(this);

        mCamera.startPreview();
        preview = true;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Error setting camera preview: " + e.getMessage());
    }

}


public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    if (mCamera != null) {

        if (preview) {
            mCamera.stopPreview();
            preview = false;

        }
        mCamera.release();
        mCamera = null;

    }

}

public static Camera getCameraInstance() {
    Camera c = null;
    try {
        c = Camera.open();
    } catch (Exception e) {

    }
    return c; 
}

@Override
public void onPreviewFrame(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
    camera.setPreviewCallback(null);
    if (data != null) {
        Camera.Parameters parameters = mCamera.getParameters();
        int imageFormat = parameters.getPreviewFormat();
        if (imageFormat == ImageFormat.NV21) {
            // Bitmap image = null;
            w = parameters.getPreviewSize().width;
            h = parameters.getPreviewSize().height;
            l = data.length;
            decodeYUV420SP(data, w, h);
        }

    }

    camera.setPreviewCallback(this);
}
```

}

```
06-22 17:41:51.159: I/QCameraHWI(191):  setPreviewWindow : X, mPreviewState = 0
06-22 17:41:51.159: I/CameraService(191): Destroying camera 0
06-22 17:41:51.159: I/QualcommCamera(191): Qint android::close_camera_device(hw_device_t*): device =0x14e1270 E
06-22 17:41:51.159: I/QCameraHWI(191): ~QCameraHardwareInterface: E
06-22 17:41:51.169: I/drawView(16359): Drwaed
06-22 17:41:51.169: E/mm_camera_poll_thread(191): mm_camera_poll_thread_release: err, poll thread of channel  0s not running. cam_id=0
06-22 17:41:51.169: E/mm_camera_poll_thread(191): mm_camera_poll_thread_release: err,   poll thread of channel  1s not running. cam_id=0
06-22 17:41:51.169: E/mm_camera_poll_thread(191): mm_camera_poll_thread_release: err, poll thread of channel  2s not running. cam_id=0
06-22 17:41:51.169: E/mm_camera_poll_thread(191): mm_camera_poll_thread_release: err, poll thread of channel  3s not running. cam_id=0
06-22 17:41:51.169: E/mm-camera(206): config_shutdown_pp Camera not in streaming mode. Returning. 
06-22 17:41:51.169: E/mm-camera(206): mctl_pp_read_pipe Got EXIT 
06-22 17:41:51.169: E/mm-camera(206): mctl_pp_clear_buf: E
06-22 17:41:51.169: E/mm-camera(206): mctl_pp_clear_buf: Check for image mode 0 num 0 count = 0 data = 0x0
06-22 17:41:51.169: E/mm-camera(206): mctl_pp_clear_buf: Check for image mode 1 num -1 count = -1 data = 0x0
06-22 17:41:51.169: E/mm-camera(206): mctl_pp_clear_buf: Check for image mode 2 num 0 count = 0 data = 0x0
06-22 17:41:51.169: E/mm-camera(206): mctl_pp_clear_buf: Check for image mode 3 num 0 count = 0 data = 0x0
06-22 17:41:51.169: E/mm-camera(206): mctl_pp_clear_buf: Check for image mode 4 num 0 count = 0 data = 0x0
06-22 17:41:51.169: E/mm-camera(206): mctl_pp_clear_buf: Check for image mode 5 num 0 count = 0 data = 0x0
06-22 17:41:51.169: E/mm-camera(206): mctl_pp_clear_buf: X
```

Comment: Nobody can help you without source code or stacktraces.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I put the code above(i delete some cods that do not need). I mainly want to get the frames of the camera and then convert it from YUV to RGB, and then do other process. It works well on an old phone, but cannot get frames on HTC one s.

Comment: parameters.setPreviewSize(960, 544); this sentence is right. And in fact I can get a preview of the camera now, but I cannot get frames using onPreviewFrame.

Comment: Is 960, 544 returned by Camera#getParameters().getSupportedPreviewSizes() ? It doesn't seem very compatible to just guess a supported size.

Answer (score 0):

Camera preview management is kind of tricky - surface view is available for  camera preview only after it has been created and surfaceChanged() was called. You shall also keep in mind to
stop preview and release camera on activity onPause() / onResume() lifecycle.   That's why it is better to couple camera management to activity and not to view class.

Nd there is no need to query camera parameters in onPreviewFrame() callback - they are not going to change as you application has camera exclusively.

You may look at samples in this project, how it is supposed to work:

http://sourceforge.net/projects/javaocr/

( check out the sources and look into demos subdirectory - unless you are interested in image processing stuff )